# How to use whitelist for frame options

Tags: sapui5, whitelist, x-frame-options

Currently I am securing the front-end side of a FIORI application. When reading the official documentation I have seen that it is possible to load a FIORI application in a frame on a trusted domain. For that we would have to implement a whitelist. The official documentation stipulates that the following steps have to be implemented:

1. Call the service:

   ```
    <meta name="sap.whitelistService" content="Whitelist.js">
   ```
2. Set the whitelist

   ```
   jQuery.sap.addUrlWhitelist(undefined, "https://webide-ad232er4.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/");
   jQuery.sap.validateUrl("https://webide-ad232er4.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/");
   ```
3. Set the frameOptions to trusted

   ```
   data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted"
   ```

   After performing all these steps as stipulated by the official documentation, through the SAP Web IDE I launch my application in a frame and normally all actions can be performed. However this is not the case, no actions can be performed and seems like the Whitelist service doesn't recognized my domain.

Is somebody able to provide guidance on how to correctly implement this?

P.S: This is the official documentation i used: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/62/d9c4d8f5ad49aa914624af9551beb7/content.htm

**EDIT**

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2014 SAP AG, All Rights Reserved -->
<head>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="sap.whitelistService" content="ui.2sp.mm.purchorder.approve.uis2pmmpurchorderapproveExtension.Whitelist.js" />

<title>Extension Project in UShell Sandbox</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window["sap-ushell-config"] = {
    defaultRenderer : "fiorisandbox",
    services: {
        NavTargetResolution: {
         // navigation target resolution service is configured to resolve the empty location hash to the application
            config : {
                resolveLocal : [ {
                    "linkId" : "",
                    resolveTo : {
                        additionalInformation : "SAPUI5.Component=ui.s2p.mm.purchorder.approve.uis2pmmpurchorderapproveExtension",
                        applicationType : "URL",
                        url : "./" + window.location.search // pass URL query parameters to application
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>

<script src="test-resources/sap/ushell/bootstrap/sandbox.js" id="sap-ushell-bootstrap"></script>
```

```
 <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-compatVersion="1.16"
    data-sap-ui-frameOptions="trusted"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"ui.s2p.mm.purchorder.approve.uis2pmmpurchorderapproveExtension": "./"}'>

</script>

<!-- Create the unified shell default renderer control and add it to the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
sap.ui.getCore().attachInitEvent(function() {
    sap.ushell.Container.createRenderer().placeAt("content");
});
</script>
</head>

<!-- UI Content -->
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

Whitelist.js

```
jQuery.sap.addUrlWhitelist("https", "uis2pmmpurchorderapproveextens-ad232er4.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/?hc_reset");
jQuery.sap.validateUrl("uis2pmmpurchorderapproveextens-ad232er4.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/?hc_reset");
```

Kinds regards,

Zakaria

Comment: I removed the mention of UI5 in the title again. The reference to UI5 is quite clear due to the used tag.

Comment: Perfect, no worries! Hope someone can help further on this topic..